# Laravel 4 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-4

```
[2014-04-28 12:34:46] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php:140 
Stack trace:

#0 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(1021): Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection->match(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#1 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(989): Illuminate\Routing\Router->findRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#2 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(968): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(738): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(708): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard.php(38): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#6 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php(72): Illuminate\Http\FrameGuard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#7 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#8 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#9 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#10 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(606): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\public\index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#12 C:\wamp\www\ppdb\index.php(19): require_once('C:\wamp\www\ppd...')
#13 {main} [] []
```

Tried to create a form with laravel , and seems fine when i load the page , the problem is when i try to submit the form this error is getting in log file.

Can anyone please check to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a `post`route? post your routes.php pls

Comment: Route::get('/', function()
{
 return View::make('hello');
});Route::controller('search','SearchController');

Comment: @pc-shooter thanks buddy , you make ma day cheers!

Comment: @pc-shooter  now solved the problem by adding a post routing in route.php "Route::post('search', 'SearchController@index');"

Comment: Put your solution into an answer for other users.

Answer (score 2):

I missed  to add post routing in routes.php

```
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@index');
```

Post routing did the job for me.
Cheers!